# $\phi : S \rightarrow \bar{S}$ an isometry, and $X:U \rightarrow S$ is a param. at a point p in S. Prove $\bar{X} = \phi \circ X$ is ...

Tags: differential-geometry

$\phi : S \rightarrow \bar{S}$ an isometry, and $X:U \rightarrow S$ is a param. at a point p in S. Prove $\bar{X} = \phi \circ X$ is a parametrization at $\phi(p)$ and$ E = \bar{E}, F = \bar{F}, G = \bar{G}$, the first fundamental form coefficients.

- From Do Carmo 4.2.2

Well $\bar{X} = \phi \circ X : U \rightarrow \phi(p) \subset \bar{S}$ is a parametrization at $\phi(p)$ since its a subset of the codomain of $\bar{X}$ I'd say. Now since $\phi$ is an isometry, we know the first fundamental form is preserved under the mapping, i.e., 
 
$I_p(x'(0))$ = $I_{\phi(p)}(d\phi(x'(0)))$  $\forall p \in X(S)$

Now I know I almost have it but 
if x = (u,v) and $\bar{X}$ = $(\bar{u},\bar{v})$ then 
 
$I_p(x'(0))$  = $E(u')^2 + 2Fu'v' + G(v')^2$ and 
$I_{\phi(p)}(d\phi(x'(0)))$ = $\bar{E}(\bar{u}')^2 + 2\bar{F}\bar{u}'\bar{v}' + \bar{G}(v')^2$ and... 
For the answer to be true we need $u=\bar{u}$ and $v = \bar{v}$ but how can we assume that?

Comment: It just seems to me $\bar{X}$ is defined differently than X implies I can't assume they're the same parametrization, or curve, etc.

Comment: I talked to my prof. and what I talked about above doesn't even make sense. So please just answer the question, I think I'm just really confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is many years overdue, but I think the answer is this:

So first you want to check that $\overline{\boldsymbol{x}}=\phi \circ \boldsymbol{x}$ is a parametrization at $\phi ( p)$. You can do this by verifying that $\overline{\boldsymbol{x}}$ satisfies all the requirements (differentiability, homeomorphism, one-to-one).

The first two follow since $\overline{\boldsymbol{x}}$ is the composition of two maps, one of which is an isometry and the other is given to be a parametrization. Then the one-to-one also kind of follows, but basically you can prove it by the following:

So you know that for some arbitrary $q \in S$ $d \overline{\mathbf{x}}_{q}=d \phi_{\phi(\mathbf{x}(q))} \cdot d \mathbf{x}$ and since $\boldsymbol{x}$ is a param, $d \boldsymbol{x}$ is one-to-one  and since $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism, $d \phi$ is one-to-one. Therefore, $\forall p \in U d \overline{\mathbf{x}}_{p}$ holds.

Now we will prove the second part, which is that $E=\overline{E}, F=\overline{F}, G=\overline{G}$. So the definition of an Isometry in the do Carmo is as follows:

> A diffeomorphism $\phi$ is an isometry if the differential $d \phi$ preserves the inner product. (page 221)

So basically, you know that $I_{p}(w)=I_{\varphi(p)}\left(d \varphi_{p}(w)\right)$ is true since $\phi$ is an isomorphism. So we can conclude that for all $p \in \boldsymbol{x}(U), w \in T_{p}(S)$

$$\begin{aligned} I_{p}(w) &=E\left(u^{\prime}\right)^{2}+2 F u^{\prime} v^{\prime}+G\left(v^{\prime}\right)^{2} \\ I_{\varphi(p)}\left(d \varphi_{p}(w)\right) &=\overline{E}\left(u^{\prime}\right)^{2}+2 \overline{F} u^{\prime} v^{\prime}+\overline{G}\left(v^{\prime}\right)^{2} \end{aligned}$$

The two are equivalent and this works for all curves $\alpha(t)=(u(t), v(t)) \in U$. So then you can verify by taking coordinate curves that $E=\overline{E}, F=\overline{F}, G=\overline{G}$ is true.